# Insert time with a button depending what field is click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 5 fields and i want to automatically insert time (24 hour format) when field is click (or button click), instead of having 5 buttons, i want to display 1 for all.

code im using is

```
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

any idea how can i accomplish this?

```
$(function(){
    $('#time').click(function(){
        var time = new Date();                
        $('#time-holder').val(time.toTimeString());  
    });
});
```

in https://jsfiddle.net/cuva5y4z/

Comment: You should accept correct answers in your questions (Your previous question has a correct answer)

Comment: yes i will, i dont think it was ask correlty on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toLocaleTimeSTring` to format the time as you please. By neglecting seconds, and doing `hour12: false` in the options parameter of `toLocaleTimeString()`, the time will read as `17:28`, for example.

---

**For one input:**

```js
$(function() {
    $('#time').click(function() {
        var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: false});
        $('#time-holder').val(time);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

---

**For multiple inputs** - Apply a class to all inputs you want to affect, and target them by class.

```js
    $('#time').click(function() {
        var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: false
        });
        $('.time-input').val(time);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="FILL ALL INPUTS" name="timer" id="time"><br><br>

    <input type="text" class="time-input" id="time-holder1"><br>
    <input type="text" class="time-input" id="time-holder2"><br>
    <input type="text" class="time-input" id="time-holder3"><br>
    <input type="text" class="time-input" id="time-holder4"><br>
    <input type="text" class="time-input" id="time-holder5"><br>
```